# Combined git `continue` command

Tags: git, alias

Variously I might need to run:

- `git rebase --continue`
- `git cherry-pick --continue`
- `git revert --continue`

In each case, my command line is reminding me that I'm mid-(rebase/cp/revert) so it's clear to me that it knows which one is active.

So it feels like there could conceptually be a command `git continue` which will continue whichever operation is currently active, thus saving some tedious typing?

- A) Does this command exist already (in which case, what is it, and what does it support?
- B) How could I write this command myself, if I were so inclined? (Maybe with aliases?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to @alfunx's answer, I might suggest this change:

Instead of doing `repo_path=$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)` so git's return code & log is ignored, I changed the script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

repo_path=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit $?
fi

if [ -d "${repo_path}/rebase-merge" ]; then
    git rebase --continue
elif [ -d "${repo_path}/rebase-apply" ]; then
    git rebase --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/MERGE_HEAD" ]; then
    git merge --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD" ]; then
    git cherry-pick --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/REVERT_HEAD" ]; then
    git revert --continue
else
    echo "No something in progress?"
fi
```

Now this script...

1. returns corresponding exit code(for example, `128` for not being a git repository, etc) and error message from git binary itself(like `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`)
2. `echo "No something in progress?"` if there was nothing going on.

Comment: If `~/bin` is in your `$PATH` variable, you don't need the alias (more on that in `man git` in the description of `--list-cmds`).

Comment: @alfunx Thank you, I checked my PATH again and found out that I was totally wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Such a command does not exist, to my knowledge. However you could create a script for that, called e.g. `git-continue`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

repo_path=$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)

if [ -d "${repo_path}/rebase-merge" ]; then
    git rebase --continue
elif [ -d "${repo_path}/rebase-apply" ]; then
    git rebase --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/MERGE_HEAD" ]; then
    git merge --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD" ]; then
    git cherry-pick --continue
elif [ -f "${repo_path}/REVERT_HEAD" ]; then
    git revert --continue
fi
```

Put the script somewhere in your `$PATH`, and then you can use `git continue`.

Note that there are similar flags like `--continue`, for example `--abort`, `--skip`, `--quit`, which you might want to cover as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this as a powershell function, here it is:

```
# Continues the ongoing git operation.
function git-continue {
    $repoPath = git rev-parse --git-dir

    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        exit $LASTEXITCODE
    }

    if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $repoPath "rebase-merge") -PathType Container) {
        git rebase --continue
    }
    elseif (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $repoPath "rebase-apply") -PathType Container) {
        git rebase --continue
    }
    elseif (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $repoPath "MERGE_HEAD") -PathType Leaf) {
        git merge --continue
    }
    elseif (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $repoPath "CHERRY_PICK_HEAD") -PathType Leaf) {
        git cherry-pick --continue
    }
    elseif (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $repoPath "REVERT_HEAD") -PathType Leaf) {
        git revert --continue
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "fatal: No operation in progress?"
    }
}
```

It can be made into an alias using:
`git config --global alias.continue "!pwsh -command 'git-continue'"`

---

Inspired by [@ik1ne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53370600/5561649).